# wxPython : Free Style Graphics

Tags: python, wxpython

I am fairly new to wxPython on Linux OS. I have been trying to create a GUI screen as below.

But it seems wxPython it is difficult to do so as I am facing problems listed below:

1. Cannot have buttons placed over an image with the same look and feel like - "Choose operating type", "Statistics" and "Back"?
2. Being able to set button colors as required below? Further the button needs to be curved at edges
3. Labels of button text to be wrapped?

Code:

```
import wx

########################################################################
class MainPanel(wx.Panel):
    """"""

    #----------------------------------------------------------------------
    def __init__(self, parent):
        """Constructor"""
        wx.Panel.__init__(self, parent=parent)
        self.SetBackgroundStyle(wx.BG_STYLE_CUSTOM)
        self.frame = parent

        sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        hSizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)

        for num in range(2):
            label = "Choose To Change Address" # Sample Button 
            btn = wx.Button(self, label=label)
            sizer.Add(btn, 0, wx.ALL, 5)
        hSizer.Add((1,1), 1, wx.EXPAND)
        hSizer.Add(sizer, 0, wx.TOP, 100)
        hSizer.Add((1,1), 0, wx.ALL, 75)
        self.SetSizer(hSizer)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_ERASE_BACKGROUND, self.OnEraseBackground)

    #----------------------------------------------------------------------
    def OnEraseBackground(self, evt):
        """
        Add a picture to the background
        """
        # yanked from ColourDB.py
        dc = evt.GetDC()

        if not dc:
            dc = wx.ClientDC(self)
            rect = self.GetUpdateRegion().GetBox()
            dc.SetClippingRect(rect)
        dc.Clear()
        bmp = wx.Bitmap("sample.png")
        dc.DrawBitmap(bmp, 0, 0)


########################################################################
class MainFrame(wx.Frame):
    """"""

    #----------------------------------------------------------------------
    def __init__(self):
        """Constructor"""
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, None, size=(320, 243), style=wx.DEFAULT_FRAME_STYLE ^ wx.RESIZE_BORDER)
        panel = MainPanel(self)        
        self.Center()

########################################################################
class Main(wx.App):
    """"""

    #----------------------------------------------------------------------
    def __init__(self, redirect=False, filename=None):
        """Constructor"""
        wx.App.__init__(self, redirect, filename)
        dlg = MainFrame()
        dlg.Show()

#----------------------------------------------------------------------
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = Main()
    app.MainLoop()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably you have to create own button class with own drawing function

Or you can use buttons made by others.

See examples on [wxpython-a-tour-of-buttons-part-2-of-2/](http://www.blog.pythonlibrary.org/2010/06/10/wxpython-a-tour-of-buttons-part-2-of-2/)